# Why is my global variable still undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a return parameter in a function that's assigned to my global variable. But when I try to use it in another function, it doesn't give back any value just `undefined`. I read this [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
to know how to use global variables, but it doesn't work in turn I made after the example.

```js
var bookTitle = asksForBookTitle();

function asksForBookTitle() {
  var docBookTitle = document.getElementById('addbook-book-title');
  var valBoodTitle = docBookTitle.value;
  return valBoodTitle;
}

function getBookTitle() {
  alert(bookTitle);
}
```

```html
<input id="addbook-book-title" type="text" name="Book Title" placeholder="Book Title">

<button id="btn-save" type="button" onclick="getBookTitle()"> Save </button>
```

Comment: A few things, given that you're writing this in 2018: don't use `onclick`, set up your event listeniner in JS: `document.getElementById('btn-save').addEventListener("click", evt => getBookTitle())`. Also, while function declarations do get hoisted, that's not a thing you want others to have to guess at: call functions after you defined them to keep the code understandable. Finally, don't use `alert()`. Just use the console api with `console.log(whatever, you, "need", {shown}, [here]);` because it logs everything, without blocking the thread, and without forcing string coercion.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning to the global variable before the user enters any data. This is the fixed version:

```js
var bookTitle;

function asksForBookTitle() {
  var docBookTitle = document.getElementById('addbook-book-title');
  var valBoodTitle = docBookTitle.value;
  return valBoodTitle;
}

function getBookTitle() {
  bookTitle = asksForBookTitle();
  alert(bookTitle);
}
```

```html
<input id="addbook-book-title" type="text" name="Book Title" placeholder="Book Title">

<button id="btn-save" type="button" onclick="getBookTitle()"> Save </button>
```

You do not even need to have a global variable for this:

```js
function getBookTitle() {
  var docBookTitle = document.getElementById('addbook-book-title');
  var valBoodTitle = docBookTitle.value;
  alert(valBoodTitle);
}
```

```html
<input id="addbook-book-title" type="text" name="Book Title" placeholder="Book Title">

<button id="btn-save" type="button" onclick="getBookTitle()"> Save </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring and assigning the value of `bookTitle` when your program starts and before the user has had the chance to enter any input. When you log it in your `alert`, your are logging that value and not the value inside of the input.